# installing package had non-zero exit status

Tags: r

I am trying to install, gamlj package using devtools but running into issue. I have java on my computer.

I clicked on #3 to not update any of the CRAN packages.

```
> devtools::install_github("gamlj/gamlj")
Downloading GitHub repo gamlj/gamlj@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?


 1: All                               
 2: CRAN packages only                
 3: None                              
 4: cli      (3.3.0  -> 3.4.1 ) [CRAN]
 5: vctrs    (0.4.2  -> 0.5.1 ) [CRAN]
 6: ps       (1.7.1  -> 1.7.2 ) [CRAN]
 7: processx (3.7.0  -> 3.8.0 ) [CRAN]
 8: jsonlite (1.8.2  -> 1.8.3 ) [CRAN]
 9: digest   (0.6.29 -> 0.6.30) [CRAN]
10: minqa    (1.2.4  -> 1.2.5 ) [CRAN]
11: lme4     (1.1-30 -> 1.1-31) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 3
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\alain\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQThCPp\remotes56fc11dc4de0\gamlj-gamlj-46644fc/DESCRIPTION'
-  preparing 'gamlj': (394ms)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'gamlj_2.6.6.tar.gz'
```

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/alain/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'gamlj' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'vctrs' 0.4.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required
  Calls:  ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'gamlj'
- removing 'C:/Users/alain/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/gamlj'
  Warning message:
  In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/alain/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQThCPp/file56fc5d804c72/gamlj_2.6.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Update your R and RStudio.

Comment: As the output says, the recommendation is to update all of the outdated packages including `vctrs`, which is the one causing the issue: >= 0.5.0 is required but your system has 0.4.2.